# preciso espremer meu layout quando abre o teclado

Tags: android, xml

Estou usando um `TableLayout` que contem `EditText`, e quando o foco está no `EditText` o teclado abre e fica na frente de informações importantes, gostaria de poder espremer o layout quando abrir o teclado. Para o meu layout inteiro (que antes ocupava a tela toda) fique inteiro visível com o teclado aberto. Isso é possível?

Alguém pode me dar umas dicas ou mostrar uma literatura/tutorial?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etdescricao"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etl5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etl1"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etl2"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etl3"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etl4"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btSalvar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:text="Salvar"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtPrevious2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:text="@string/previous"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tvp2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:textSize="75sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btNext2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:text="@string/Next"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:src="@drawable/logostar" />
            <!-- android:background="#000000" -->

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Você quer que o seu layout redimensione ao surgir o teclado?

Comment: sim, que fique menor, tipo que a tela seja sempre visivel.
quero diminuir o tamanho das linhas para que quando aparecer o teclado n some nada.

Comment: mas ao mesmo tempo quero deixar autoajustável para diferentes tamanhos de tela... vou postar meu xml

Comment: não queria que os botoes desaparecessem nem o numero da página e desse para editar todos os edittext sem fechar o teclado

Comment: Expremer o layout seria um péssimo resultado, em celulares que tem a tela pequena perderia muito em
qualidade visual, ocerto é encapsular seu layout dentro de um scrollview igual o Cícero Moura respondeu.

Comment: @Juarez A aplicação é apenas para tablets, mas valew,
acho que vou fazer sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é colocar seu layout dentro de um ScrollView e quando o teclado abrir, o usuário poderá rolar o layout para ver a informação que desejar.

Ficaria assim:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etdescricao"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etl5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etl1"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etl2"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etl3"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etl4"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et14"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et15"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btSalvar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                    android:text="Salvar"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BtPrevious2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                    android:text="@string/previous"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tvp2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:textSize="75sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btNext2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                    android:text="@string/Next"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:src="@drawable/logostar" />
                <!-- android:background="#000000" -->

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: sim perfeito, o problema é que agora ele nao volta!!

Comment: Como assim não volta, o teclado não volta?

Comment: o teclado volta, o que nao volta é o layout, ele fica expremido

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears

Answer (score 0):

Um atributo que funcionaria para o seu caso é `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, o que ele faz, é alinhar a *view* sempre a cima do teclado (quando o mesmo surgir).

Mas você precisa estar usando `RelativeLayout`.

Quer maiores informações e exemplos?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401828/598170)