# Não estou conseguindo modificar o layout ao abrir o teclado

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Estou tentando "diminuir" o layout ao abrir o teclado, mas não estou conseguindo, ele está dentro de um `ScrollView` e percebi que ele ignora o espaço livre abaixo das views (onde não há views), mas não ignora o que fica acima delas (aqui mostrando o layout com o teclado aberto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itrBo.jpg, tem mais um edittext lá embaixo q não aparece, da pra ver isso no xml), tem como eu ignorar ele ao abrir o teclado? Já vi em alguns tópicos aqui no site (esse [preciso espremer meu layout quando abre o teclado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37779/preciso-espremer-meu-layout-quando-abre-o-teclado) deu a idéia do `ScrollView`), mas nenhum funcionou, tentei usar o `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` como a resposta desse tópico https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears indica, com essa linha ou sem ela o layout fica a mesma coisa, alguém sabe como resolver?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ToBuy.ToBuy" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".EditItemActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Informações do Item:" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Nome"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:id="@+id/eTNome" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Preço"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/eTPreco" />
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sBImport"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:max="99"
                android:progress="33" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tVImport"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1. Baixa importância" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_help" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:hint="Anotações extras (opcional)"
                android:minLines="4"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:id="@+id/eTNotas" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Teria como colocar um print/foto da tela do app quando ele está da forma "errada" que você mencionou?

Comment: @perozzo a tela não fica "errada" ela fica como estava com o teclado fechado, eu queria que ela fosse "espremida" e ficasse tudo na parte visível, meio que ignorar os espaços em branco, tentei no `Android Studio` com o mesmo layout e tbm não funcionou (tem uma foto dele no link imgur ali, não coloquei na pergunta pq achei que ia ficar muito grande)